# Can I call people to discuss an old question again?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, old-questions, rules

I asked an interesting question here: [Tic Tac Toe perfect AI algorithm: deeper in "create fork" step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287084/tic-tac-toe-perfect-ai-algorithm-deeper-in-create-fork-step), the answer is just acceptable, not perfect.

Today, I just found a better (and, to me, perfect) solution for the problem, and would like to share, and call everyone "Hey mate, I just found a perfect solution, discuss with me again please" (I need to know if there is disadvantage in the new solution), and need new people too. Should I:

1. Un-accept the answer, and answer the question myself.
2. Comment everyone in that question to return and discuss.
3. Start a bounty on it (So new people can see it).
4. Just start a new question then answer myself.

One more question: Can I post a question to discuss about a solution? For example, I found out the algorithm to do something, and want everybody tells about its bad side, or fix it so it can be better?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. If you've found a better solution than those provided and are using that better solution, then yes, post it as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer.
2. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. This is not a place for people to come and lazily talk about a solution. There is no need to summon prior participants*. By posting an answer, you will bump the question onto the front page for a nominal period of time. People interested in the question can then click and read and perhaps offer commentary or an additional answer. If they find your solution unsatisfactory, they will give feedback via votes and comments. (*However, if you have something specific to say about another answer or comment received, continue to provide directed feedback as appropriate.)
3. Finally, if you are looking for criticisms and improvements for *working code*, the site for that is [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you, Code Review is a good site and your advice is good too!